# Send a string through an http request

Tags: javascript, string, xmlhttprequest

I am just starting to learn how to use XMLHttpRequest and I started with [this](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first) example from w3schools which I want to modify in order to send a string. This is the new code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xmlhttp;
    var str="sent string";
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
    xmlhttp.send(str);
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to output the response and see if the string was sent but the alert returns nothing. Just an empty window. What am I doing wrong?

Also, I found an example in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/sending-post-data-with-a-xmlhttprequest) which also adds these lines of code:

```
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
```

Are they always necessary? If yes, why? The code from that page also sends a string but that code doesn't work for me either.

**EDIT:**
This is my updated code, which still doesn't work. I even tried it without sending the string but still nothing happens. I am not trying it anymore in w3wschools, but instead in the right place, I do not have my code in a function anymore and made the changes that @Quentin told me about:

```
<script>
var xmlhttp=null;
var str="sent_string";
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST","http://192.168.1.3:80",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", str.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xmlhttp.send(str);
xmlhttp.addEventListener('load', function () {     
    alert(this.responseText); 
    alert(xmlhttp.readyState);}
);
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use w3schools, like, ever.  In answer to your question, using a raw XmlHttpRequest is almost never a good idea.   Check out jQuery and friends, which provide a simple interface over the complexities involved: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**, you aren't waiting for the HTTP response before you try to alert the value.

```
alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

should be:

```
xmlhttp.addEventListener('load', function () {
    alert(this.responseText);
});
```

**Second**, you are making a GET request with a message body. You need a POST (or PUT) request if you want to send a request body:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax_info.txt",true);
```

**Third**, you are sending a plain text request but telling the server it is form encoded.

```
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

should be

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");
```

Comment: I changed my question so that it contains the new version of my code, which still doesn't work.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong now. What does the JS console say? What does the Net tab in your developer tools say?

Comment: JS console: The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. Other than that, nothing. And I don't think that this error helps me with anything. And in the Net tab there nothing gets displayed. Is there another way to see some errors? Or maybe try it on another website? Like the one from w3schools...

Comment: If nothing is displayed in the Net tab, then either the request isn't being made in the first place or your are opening it after the request has been made. Open it first.

Comment: I just moved the code with `setRequestHeader` before `xmlhttp.open()` and now in the Net tab I have POST and the url and HTTP/1.1 200 OK which is the response, right? So it works, but still nothing gets alerted. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send something with an ajax request there are two ways, POST, and GET.

You will have to read about it before sending anything. Just Google for REST, or HTTP POST. You will find everything.

Than I would suggest you to use AngularJS, or jQuery, instead of a raw ajax call.

For example in AngularJS, all you have to do is:

```
$http.get('mypage.php?name=john').success(function (data) {

//work with the answer in data

});
```

Comment: You might want to mention that AngularJS is a full-fledged web app framework, whereas jQuery can be dropped in as needed.